# Bootstrap column divs cover entire width of container instead of just the column width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a layout with three equal columns. In the third column I want two rows of two boxes of equal width. For some reason, the columns are not covering 1/3 width but rather the entire page width. I included my HTML and relevant CSS below.

```
<div id="about-me" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sm-col-4 md-col-4 lg-col-4 xl-col-4"></div>
        <div class="sm-col-4 md-col-4 lg-col-4 xl-col-4"></div>
        <div class="sm-col-4 md-col-4 lg-col-4 xl-col-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="sm-col-6 md-col-6 lg-col-6 xl-col-6 simple-image-box"></div>
                <div class="sm-col-6 md-col-6 lg-col-6 xl-col-6 simple-image-box"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="sm-col-6 md-col-6 lg-col-6 xl-col-6 simple-image-box"></div>
                <div class="sm-col-6 md-col-6 lg-col-6 xl-col-6 simple-image-box"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#about-me {
    height: 100vh;
}
.simple-image-box {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 40%;
    color: cadetblue;
}
```

Comment: The class name sm-col-4 should be replaced with col-sm-4. Try replacing the all other column names also.

Comment: Also, since bootstrap is mobile first, you should only need col-sm-4.  If you want it to take up the same number of columns at every screen size, then you just need the smallest one.  It will still apply for medium and large screens. Sizes cascade up.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that. Now the three columns work but the boxes still don't stay next to each other to make a 2x2 grid. All four just stack vertically.

Comment: You're overriding the width with your ```.simple-image-box``` class. You should have that be a class on a nested div and not on the div that's using bootstraps built in grid system

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks @jtmingus

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `type-col-number` instead of `col-type-number`.

HTML:

```
<div id="about-me" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 simple-image-box"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 simple-image-box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 simple-image-box"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 simple-image-box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```